# (Gnosis) Safe Transaction Not Showing In Metamask

Tags: metamask, gnosis-safe, safe

I have a Metamask wallet and a (Gnosis) Safe wallet on the Sepolia network. I sent some Sepolia ETH to the Safe wallet (this transaction shows correctly in Metamask). I then sent some Sepolia ETH back from Safe to Metamask. The Sepolia ETH balance in Metamask increased correctly, however, no "Receive" transaction is shown in Metamask. (When I send Sepolia ETH from one Metamask wallet to another, I see this "Receive" transaction)

My question is, is this to be expected? Does (Gnosis) Safe handle transactions somehow differently or is it due to using Sepolia testnet?

When I check the transaction (from Safe to Metamask) on Etherscan, I also see a transaction value of 0 ETH (but it says: transfer x ETH from A to B in the "To" section).

Furthermore, when I sign transactions on Safe, I also see Gas and SafeGas estimates. Don't really understand what Gnosis Safe is doing here.

Thank you very much for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue on Metamask side.
Regarding Safe transactions showing value of 0 ETH, this is expected because the Safe transaction is not a transfer, but a call to a function in the Safe contract instead. The real transfer from the Safe to the destination is happening as an internal transaction

Comment: Ah, all clear. Thank you very much! Do you also know what this SafeGas should be? A different type of gas?